# Distribution of $\max(X,Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are lognormal and you know $\min(X,Y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider two arbitrary lognormal random variables $X$ and $Y$ with correlation $\rho$. Suppose you are given the distribution for $\min(X,Y)$. Express the distribution of $\max(X,Y)$ in terms of $\min(X,Y)$?

I'm trying to use the relationship that $\max(X,Y)= -\min(-X,-Y)$. But I'm stuck because $-X$ and $-Y$ are not lognormal so I can't apply the min formula.

Comment: It looks like you mean to express the pdf of the $\max(X, Y)$ in terms of the given pdf of $\min(X, Y)$. Not sure if the question could mean the conditional distribution of $\max(X, Y) \mid \min(X, Y)$

Comment: @BGM Yes, I updated the question to express $\max(X,Y)$ in terms of $\min(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this falls into any standard family. You can write

$$P\left(\max\left(X,Y\right) \leq z\right) = P\left(X \leq z, Y\leq z\right).$$

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then this simplifies to a product of two lognormal cdfs, which you can then differentiate to get the density. It will be some ugly mixture distribution though.

As you observed, there doesn't seem to be any symmetry between maximum and minimum for lognormal distributions. You can write

$$P\left(\min\left(X,Y\right) > z\right) = P\left(X > z, Y > z\right)$$

to get the product of two tail probabilities (in case of independence), but this doesn't seem to have a clean mapping to the previous case.

Or do you mean that the minimum value $\min\left(X,Y\right)$ is given and you are calculating a conditional distribution of the maximum?

Comment: X and Y are not independent. I meant to express $\max(X,Y)$ as a function of  $\min(X,Y)$. I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a paper you have probably seen that discusses the minimum and maximum for bivariate lognormals, but it is limited to the moments, so it seems unlikely that there is any such property: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10687-005-4861-8

Comment: thanks for sharing, in that paper, he doesn't state the moments of the $Z =\max(X,Y)$. Is that supposed to be obvious?

Comment: The paper cites an earlier paper by Ker which gives those moments (but again without any property of the kind that you want).

Comment: That paper by Ker referenced is for normal, not lognormal.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Looking at the other cited reference, he derives the moments for the minimum through events applied to a bivariate normal distribution. I think the maximum can be studied this way as well by symmetry; the moments probably just have the parameters or signs switched. I think mimicking the arguments of that reference is the best option.